# Oracle :: identifier 'SYS.DBMS_SHARED_POOL' must be declared

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, oracle12.1

My oracle database version is: 12.1.0.2.0

I'm trying to purge a cursor from share pool using dbms_shared_pool.purge procedure.
It works fine if I execute it as standalone command like below -

```
SQL> exec sys.DBMS_SHARED_POOL.PURGE('0000000BEF761888,1227751471', 'C', 1);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

However, if I put this statement inside a procedure & invoke the procedure then it fails.

```
SQL> create or replace procedure test_sp
is
  s_sql varchar2(2000);
begin
  s_sql := q'[begin sys.DBMS_SHARED_POOL.PURGE('0000000BEF761888,1227751471', 'C', 1); end;]';
  execute immediate s_sql;
end;
/
  2    3    4    5    6    7    8
Procedure created.

SQL>
SQL> show err
No errors.
SQL>
```

Error:

```
SQL> exec test_sp;
BEGIN test_sp; END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00201: identifier 'SYS.DBMS_SHARED_POOL' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06512: at "ORADBA.TEST_SP", line 6
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

User executing standalone command & and the one that created & invoked procedure is same. The user has privileges to invoke dbms_share_pool.purge as standalone command executes successfully.

So, why does it fail when the same procedure is invoked via another procedure?

Thanks,
Kailash

Comment: Why are you using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE? A procedure call like this has no need of being abstracted dynamically.

Comment: This is sample code. My target procedure defines sql using place holder. sql_stmt := q'[begin sys.DBMS_SHARED_POOL.PURGE(:1, 'C', 1); end;]'; It then executes this within cursor for-loop which identifies cursors that needs to be purged passing value for placeholder.

Comment: Still, there's no need for dynamic SQL. You should simply call dbms_shared_pool_purge directly. Let's say your procedure has params in_parm1, in_parm2... then in your body you should say dbms_shared_pool.purge(in_parm1,'C',in_parm2); If you are getting an error on compilation, that's probably due to your permissions issue. You want to find out about that at compile time, not run time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the privilege is granted through a role then you won't be able to include the statement within a PL/SQL procedure. You must have the execute privilege on the object granted directly to your user.

Comment: ```GRANTEE OWNER TABLE_NAME GRANTOR PRIVILEGE
EXECUTE_CATALOG_ROLE SYS DBMS_SHARED_POOL SYS EXECUTE```

Yes, privilege is granted via role. Is this limitation of roles granted by SYS? I believe this is common scenario where administrative user owns all objects and grants privilege to application user via role.

Comment: Oracle has never honored object permissions obtained through roles in named PL/SQL routines. You have to get an explicit object grant. It's always been this way, for decades.